# How to use middle wheel of a bluetooth mouse for zoom in and out in app?

Tags: applications, mouse

I bought a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Bluetooth Mouse (H3S-00003) recently to connect to my Samsung S5. There is a middle wheel in the mouse. I could use the wheel to scroll down and up in my Android Chrome.

Some of my apps (e.g. Solidworks viewer) allow using two fingers to zoom in and out. For the desktop version of the app, I can use the middle wheel function for zoom and and out. Is it possible to set the Android bluetooth mouse to do the same thing as the desktop version using the middle wheel?